# Insert new row in the same place in two sheets > copy formulas from above

Tags: vba, excel

I've created a tracking document for my workplace, but my limited knowledge of Excel has only taken me so far. Hoping there's someone out there who enjoys cleaning up messy workbooks...

I have a document with two connected worksheets: 'Annuals', covering a lot of detail about the forms I'm designing; and 'Summary', which is really intended for management use. All the information in the 'Summary' page is a cell reference to 'Annuals' and the 'Summary' page is normally password protected so that the formulas can't be overwritten. You can download a dummy copy of the larger document I'm hoping to implement: [Dropbox Link](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/29546718/Tracking%20Document%20Help.xls) We use Excel 2010 at work, although the attached document was last edited in OpenOffice Calc.

The basic function of this document is to present varying degrees of information per worksheet, with most raw information being manually provided. I would like it to be dynamic enough that the user doesn't need to understand the importance of keeping cell references - they can just press a button to add their task to the list, and the program will populate the rest behind the scenes.

Aside from the terrible way that I've visually indicated the row label "hierarchy" in column C, I'm also having issues when someone wishes to insert a new row in the 'Annuals' page; I have not found an effective way to insert a row on the 'Summary' page at the same time while maintaining dynamic formulas and formatting. It has been difficult to write a macro to do this because I only want certain cells referenced on the 'Summary' page (although I'm 100% sure there's a way to do this).

This is my attempt:

```
Public sAddress As String

Sub AddRow()
R = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveCell.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("E" & R & ":G" & R).Copy Destination:=Range("E" & R + 1 & ":G" & R + 1)
Range("T" & R).Copy Destination:=Range("T" & R + 1)
End Sub

Sub DeleteRow()
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Sub AddSummary()
On Error Resume Next
Worksheets("Summary").Activate
If sAddress > "" Then Sh.Range(sAddress).Select
R = ActiveCell.Row
ActiveCell.Offset(-1).EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown
Range("E" & R & ":G" & R).Copy Destination:=Range("E" & R + 1 & ":G" & R + 1)
Range("T" & R).Copy Destination:=Range("T" & R + 1)
End Sub

Sub Variab()
sAddress = ActiveCell.Address
End Sub

Sub Everything()
Call AddRow
Call Variab
Call AddSummary
End Sub
```

Maybe a pivot table could be implemented? However, I have no idea how to make a pivot table actually work, let alone make it user-friendly or pretty. I tried - and failed - to make a pivot table that I could reference in the Summary page and hide from other users, but I didn't get very far.

I know that you're probably shuddering at my workbook, but if you can think of better methodology behind the information I'm trying to track (amongst many users, with varying degrees of computer literacy) then *please* let me know!

Answer (score 0):

Click on Summary tab
Shift-click on Annuals tab
Insert the row.

That's it! It will insert a blank row on both sheets.

If you want to copy data from an existing row into the newly created row (as in your macro), select both tabs as above, highlight a row, copy it, and paste it into the new row. You will see that the copy command was applied to both sheets, just as if you had done the copy command  on each sheet.